# XQuery: extract number from string to use in comparison

Tags: parsing, xpath, numbers, xquery

I am very new to XQuery, and frankly find the learning curve incredibly steep.

I have an XML structure that looks something like this:

```
<root>
    <product>
        <size>500 units</size>
    </product>
    <product>
        <size>1000 units</size>
    </product>
    <product>
        <size>Unlimited units</size>
    </product>
</root>
```

I need to write an XQuery statement that returns all nodes where the numerical value in **size** is less than say 1000. So I somehow need to determine this numerical value (ignoring any text) to perform an 'le' operation I assume.

On top of this, there is the possibility that the node will have no digits at all (e.g. 'Unlimited units'), in which case it needs to be treated as having a value of say 1000000.

Is there some way to do this? I've tried various combinations of **fn:replace(blah, '\D', '')** and casting to xs:int, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
/root/product[not(number(substring-before(size, ' ')) >= 1000)]
```

As we all know well, XPath is a subset of XQuery, so the above is also an XQuery expression.

Comment: +1 Better expression if matching maximum value won't be needed.

Comment: @Alejandro: The meaning of "unlimited nodes" is just that: "bigger than anything."

Comment: Yes, but you know that `NaN` has special rules, and that's the reason for the double negative expression ("not greater" instead of just "less than"). So, for "greater than" 500, you would need "not less than" as in `/root/product[not(500 >= substring-before(size, ' '))]`. That wouldn't be clear for everybody.

Comment: @Alejandro: There is always something that "wouldn't be clear for everybody" -- if they just copy and use the expression from my answer as a "fill-in the blanks" expression, they don't need to have a too deep understanding.

Answer (score 2):

This XQuery:

```
for $vProduct in /root/product
let $vUnits := number(substring-before($vProduct/size,'units'))
let $vSize := if ($vUnits)
              then $vUnits
              else 1000000
where $vSize le 1000
return $vProduct
```

Output:

```
<product>
    <size>500 units</size>
</product>
<product>
    <size>1000 units</size>
</product>
```

Comment: +1, but I have shown that just a simple XPath expression suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use the `fn:tokenize(subject, pattern, flags)` (here is an description of the [tokenize](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_tokenize.html)) function to extract your int values. The `tokenize` function will return an array with your int values in the first position of the array. You can then do whatever you want with your int values.

To distinguish between the cases where the units are given and the "Unlimited units" case, you could do a regexp `fn:match` with "Unlimited units" or simply compare the string before tokenizing. If the string is "Unlimited units" you'd treat is ar necessary and in the other case you tokenize the string to extract the int value.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of repetition for the sake of clarity

```
/root/product[not(substring-before(size," ") castable as xs:integer) or xs:integer(substring-before(size," ")) < 1000]
```

A bit of repetition for the sake of clarity